Might [NP, not NP] be a form of correlation?
I have a new question with reference to the following sentence (as it appeared in NP, not NP - Apposition, Coordination or Something Else?):

(1) I want cake, not candy.

Could it be that NP, not NP constructs are merely a reformulation of not ... but ... correlations?
In other words, I'm asking whether the above sentence is a reformulation of the following sentence:

(2) I want not candy but cake.

My sense of not ... but ... correlations is that their focus is on the negative element, with the negative element having been introduced earlier in the discourse. Inverting the sequence and omitting the but seems to move the focus to the affirmative element, away from negative element. This effect can be particularly useful in cases in which the speaker wishes to draw a contrast but the negative element has not yet been mentioned.
.
.
.

Some Discussion of the Concept
This line of inquiry was motivated by a more complex example from a corpus. Rather than NP, not NP, that example involves P S, not P S (a/k/a AdvCl, not AdvCl):

(3) American colonists, according to historian T.H. Breen, “obeyed the Navigation Acts [because it was convenient and profitable for them to do so][, not because they were coerced].”

In that example, the focus is on the obedience being of a self-interested, voluntary nature. The afterthought regarding coercion serves to emphasize that point. The analysis suggested by my question seems to apply equally to that example. Put back into not ... but ... form, it would read:

(4) American colonists, according to historian T.H. Breen, “obeyed the Navigation Acts [not because they were coerced] [but because it was convenient and profitable for them to do so].”

That form happens to be awkward for the context because the preceding discourse makes no mention of the concept of coercion. Mentioning it as the first element of the not ... but ... correlation might be jarring in that context. Avoiding that effect while still drawing the desired contrast seems to have been achieved by inverting the negative and affirmative elements and eliding the 'but'.
With all that said, I wonder whether the word not, standing between parallel phrases, could simply be regarded as a one-word, stand-alone correlative conjunction. Consider:

(5) She smiled [at me] first[, not at you]. [PP correlation]
(6) He gave it [to Smeagol] for his birthday[, not to Deagol]. [PP correlation]
(7) The bevels are [ridiculous, but] [fortunately not too noticeable]. [AdjP correlation]

(7) seems to be a clear case in which but ... not ... doesn't work, which suggests that perhaps but not and but ADV not may also fit the mold of being stand-alone correlative conjunctions when placed (roughly) between two parallel phrases.
.
.
.

Further Discussion -- Alternatives
Not-Stripping: In the question linked, above, one particularly helpful possible answer was Not-Stripping. The explanation suggested, here, seems much simpler than Not-Stripping. It is worth noting that Not-Stripping reportedly often involves 'but not' introducing the so-called remnant phrase. A prototypical example used in a paper on Not-Stripping is:

Mary ate an apple, but not an orange.

Applying the suggestion made by this question, this sort of example of Not-Stripping instead would be explained as simply being a rearrangement of:

Mary ate not an orange but an apple.

None of this is to suggest that dissimilar instances of Not-Stripping can be so explained.
Supplementation: Another very helpful answer to the earlier question was to analyze the ", not NP" as a case of supplementation, a la CamGEL at Ch. 15. I was very close to concluding that supplementation is the best analysis, but was troubled by two aspects of the matter, both revolving around the "indicator", in the parlance of CamGEL (i.e., a word or phrase that helps to connect the supplement to a constituent in the matrix clause). First, 'not' is not among the typical indicators mentioned in CamGEL (e.g., namely, that is, for example, to wit), and given the frequency with which 'not' occurs in this form, it seems like it would have been listed had the authors considered such cases to constitute supplementation. Second, as a negator, 'not' has a variety of special properties that feel slightly out of place when compared with other adverbs that commonly act as indicators.

The "not X, but Y" form is often used in a context where there's an expectation that X will be true, and we want to stress that this is incorrect. This could be because there has been previous mention of X, but it also could be due to implicit assumptions that are likely.
Even if the audience doesn't actually have that assumption, forming the sentence like this implies that the speaker believes that this assumption is in place.
Consider this famous line from John F. Kennedy:

Ask not what your country can do for you, but what you can do for your country.

This implies that people are assumed to be self-centered, and says we need to counter that natural inclination with public service.
When the X has been mentioned, we can be more forceful, and write something like.

No, I don't want candy, I want cake.

You can't generally start with the negation "No" if there's nothing prior to negate.

'The "not X, but Y" form is often used in a context where there's an expectation that X will be true', and/or where X rather than Y  has been provided / is the existing situation. // This explains/illustrates the meaning and context involved, but OP asks about evolution of the different variants. I doubt he'll get an answer showing convincing research.
